# Code jquery in a different file then html

Tags: adobe-brackets

In brackets now I can only code jQuery inside the  lines of my html file.
But now I want to code jQuery in another file, but of course I stall want that it interact with the html, for example that I can still target the divs:
$(".navbar")

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: @OğuzTanrıkulu if I make an jquery.js file and I paste the following code into my html: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min"></script> I can make jQuery code inside my html-file, but now I want to create a new file in which i can code jQuery.

Comment: Firstly you are trying to insert 2 jquery library, insert only one of them. Secondly, simple create any .js file insert it in html and code.

Comment: @OğuzTanrıkulu so I did create an .js file, but if I type in my simple jquery code: `$(".navbar").click(function(){
    $(".navbar").hide();
});
$(document).ready();` it says: $ was used before it was defined.

Comment: can you share your all html and js  codes?

Comment: @OğuzTanrıkulu `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javscript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
   <body><div class="navbar"><p>Hello</p></div></body>` Here the jquery: `$(".navbar").click(function(){
$(".navbar").hide();
});
$(document).ready();`

Comment: could you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the reason why I can't have the jQuery-code in another file is a glitch in Brackets.

Answer (score 0):

HTML File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta name="description" content="Test"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javscript" src="Javascript.js"</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS File :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").click(function(){ 
        $(".navbar").hide();
    });
});
```